# Why can't I properly style a blockquote in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

On the design I just created for my website, I have a blockquote styled with two quote images using the span technique in css:

```
blockquote {
background-image: url(images/openquote.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left 5px;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
font-style: italic;
}

blockquote span {
background-image: url(images/closequote.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right bottom;
display: block;
padding-right: 30px;
font-style: italic;
}
```

Then I format the HTML like this:

```
<blockquote><span>
"The worst part of writing fiction is the fear of wasting your life behind a keyboard. The idea that, dying, you'll realize that you only ever lived on paper. Your only adventures were make-believe, and while the world fought and kissed, you sat in some dark room, masturbating and making money."<br /><br /><b><div align="right">- Chuck Palahniuk</div></b>
</span></blockquote>
```

On the test HTML page I created, the quote works fine and shows up exactly how I wanted to.  Now that I'm transferring all of my coding to Wordpress, however, the blockquote doesn't show up the same way.

**HTML:** lifesgarbage.com/rebnation.html (sorry, I can't post more than one link yet)

**Wordpress:** http://test.lifesgarbage.com

How can I change my CSS so it shows up on Wordpress similar to the way it does on the regular HTML?

Comment: You can use the Web Developer Toolbar or Firebug to find out which Wordpress CSS is overwriting your custom one.

Comment: @Pekka Gaiser: I second that - Firebug specifically.  It'll change your life.  It shows the styles applied to a tag from least specific to most, and shows you which styles are overriding others.  If you find an element that appears to have a style but it's not there, look to the parent element.
Firebug is the reason that FireFox is the goto HTML/CSS debugging browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is that wordpress defines the default MARGIN for the blockquote tag to 0. You should just add an explicit margin value in your css.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure where to add this explicit margin value?  In the image you've supplied, I see a "reset.css" which is is resetting the blockquote margin.  Is it possible to just access the reset.css and change the values there?  I can't do it through the Wordpress panel.  Why is this "reset" even there at all?

Answer (score 0):

also, wordpress is inserting a < p > tag after the < blockquote >. Maybe try using < p class="blockquote" > and style as .blockquote{margin:x; padding:x;}

The left margin doesn't seem to be part of the blockquote style, so the < p > might be resetting something.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that WP wraps the content inside an auto-generated `<p>` tag, hence you should modify your CSS to take that into account as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the blockquotes explicitly using something like this:

```
.entry-content blockquote > p { }
```

That should work on regular Wordpress installations.

Answer (score -1):

With Wordpress you can add a filter in the content to do exactly what you wish to get a great block quote

I have a blog post on this that can answer this question.

[blockquote tutorial](http://madbohem.com/tips/building-block-quotes-in-a-wordpress-theme/)